# JSON Nested Data and MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Thanks in advance for you help.  I've been searching for hours and haven't found the answer to this seemingly simple issue.  I'm still a novice with MVC and also with SO so please be kind.

I inherited this project from a previous dev, and foolishly expected this to be easy, but it's proving difficult.

I'm migrating from one API to another, and so far most model changes have gone very smoothly.  Unfortunately, I've hit a wall with this one.

Here is an example of the JSON response:

```
{
    "attendeeid":"123456789",
    "registrationstatus":"Confirmed",
    "testregistration":"1",

    "category":{
        "categoryid":"987654321",
        "name":"MERIT"
},

"subcategory":"",
"approvalstatus":"",
"discountcode":"",
"individualcost":"0.00",
"groupcount":2,
"cost":"0.00",
"totalcost":"0.00",
"received":"0.00",
"imiscontactid":null,
"recordid":"0cH+Z7x8gZLzORzXej39Ew==",
"responses":
[
    {
        "questionid":"12211221",
        "fieldname":"email",
        "name":"Email Address",
        "pageid":"1",
        "page":"Welcome",
        "choicekey":"jdoe@website.com",
        "response":"jdoe@website.com"
    },
    {
        "questionid":"12211221",
        "fieldname":"97531",
        "name":"Please indicate the years you have been a winner?",
        "pageid":"2",
        "page":"Attendee Information",
        "choicekey":"","response":["2012","2010","2009"]
    }
],
"created":"2015-07-27 11:45:31",
"language":"eng",
"tax":"0.00",
"statetax":"0.00",
"categorycost":"0.00",
"subcategorycost":"0.00",
"agendacost":"0.00",
"optioncost":"0.00",
"hotelcost":"0.00",
"guestcost":"0.00",
"adjustments":"0.00",
"lastmodified":"2015-08-07 11:15:40",
"checkindate":"",
"invoicelink":"https:\/\/www.website.com\/ereg\/pdfinvoice.php?id=0afer%suku7%31337%4779%82%3d"
}
```

Note the nesting.

Here's my model:

```
    public class Respons {
        [Key]
        [Column("QuestionID")]
        public string questionid { get; set; }

        public string EventID { get { return Controllers.RequestQueueController.GetEventID(); } set { } }

        public int AttendeeID { get { return int.Parse(Controllers.RequestQueueController.GetAttID()); } set { } }

        [Column("QuestionText")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Column("AnswerText")]
        public object response { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer {
        public string AnswerID { get { return attendeeid + "-" + EventID + responses[0].questionid; } set { } }

        public string EventID { get { return Controllers.RequestQueueController.GetEventID(); } set { } }

        [Column("AttendeeID")]
        public int attendeeid { get; set; }

        public List<Respons> responses { get; set; }

        [Column("AnsweredDate")]
        public string created { get; set; }

        [Column("ModifiedDate")]
        public string lastmodified { get; set; }
    }
```

As you've probably seen, I'm making a silly attempt to access questionid in Respons from the AnswerID in Answer.  This is just to show what I want to do.  The response from the original API had no nesting and so, we were able to generate a unique AnswerID using EventID + AttendeeID + QuestionID with the data in the Answer class, however, my attempts to access questionid in Respons from Answer have resulted in null values because, as far as I can tell, Respons hasn't been filled yet.

So, my question is.  Is there a way for me access data nested in Respons from Answer in the model, and if not, is there a way for me to update the data before adding it to the context(see below)?

eg.(I've tried this, but it hasn't yet allowed me to alter the value for a model field from the controller, I'm sure there must be a way, but I haven't found it yet)
Model:

```
public string AnswerID { get { return attendeeid + EventID + ":fill:"; } set { } }
```

Controller:

```
foreach(var answer in answers){
    answer.AnswerID = answer.AnswerID.Replace(":fill:", answer.responses[i].questionid);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. If I got it right, you've got it figured out already!